# jquery autocomplete with fulltext mysql research

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I try to install adress search form using jquery autocomplete and mysql query with Full Text research (home made dbb). But my script doesn't works...
The research take just my first character and don't loop when I write the entire word.
For this research : "Street 1"
Firebug indicate : "GET /research.php?query=S"

My jQuery script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search-bano').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'research.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        console.log(suggestion);
    }
 });
});
```

My html script :

```
<input type="text" id="search-bano" value="">
```

My php script (research.php) :

```
$term = strip_tags(substr($_GET['query'],0, 100));
$term = utf8_decode($term);
$term = mysql_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention
if($term!="")
{

 $query = mysql_query("select * from bano where MATCH(street)  AGAINST ('$term*')");
 $suggestions = array();
 if (mysql_num_rows($query))
 {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $display=''.$row['street'].'';
        $suggestions[] = array(
        "value" => $display,    
        "idstreet" => $row['idstreet']

    )       
 }

 echo json_encode(array('suggestions' => $suggestions));
}
```

Comment: Any errors in console??

Comment: No I just have this : GET /research.php?query=S. I don't know why the loop take "S" and doesn't take the entire words, here : "Street1"